# Update middle Text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have text in column like this: `'A1 - Company City X?Y'`

Now I need to replace `Company` with `Company LTD.`.

I am using `replace()` command in SQL Server but it is not working and text is not being change

```
select replace(fieldname, 'Company', 'Company LTD.')
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: select replace('A1 - Company City X?Y', 'Company','Company LTD.') returns 'A1 - Company LTD. City X?Y'. it seems to work properly

Comment: No, I tried but it returns 'A1 - Company City X?Y' only..

Comment: It works fine for me. Try one more time, make sure to type correctly.

Comment: The code works. have you tried the code Ash mentioned and see if that works? There must be something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fieldname` use `fieldvalue`

Example:

```
UPDATE [TABLENAME]
SET [LastName] = REPLACE('fieldvalue','field','www')

Select * from [TABLENAME]
```

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
select replace('A1 - Company City X?Y', 'Company','Company LTD.') 

returns 'A1 - Company LTD. City X?Y'
```

because replace() match whole string to replace so make whole sting then compare